# Union of shapefiles to generate composite shapefile with overlap frequency count for each polygon

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, union, count, frequency

I'm new to QGIS, making the switch from ArcMap. I have 5 shapefiles of polygons representing 5 years of insect defoliation. I need to overlay the 5 years and create a new composite shapefile that is a union of all 5.

There are some areas where the polygons overlap from year to year and I want the polygons of the new composite shapefile to have an attribute field `"Number_of_Yrs"` which represent the total number of years of defoliation. The values of this field should be 1 to 5 years.

Comment: Maybe easier to realise using raster layers? Rasterize your polygons and use raster calculator.

Comment: Could you add an image showing what exactly you mean?

Comment: In ArcGIS, you'd Union the polys and encode based on the number of non-universe polygon ids (I'd use a DA Update Cursor, but the field calculator would do it)

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert the polygons to lines - `Menu Vector / Geometry tools / Polygons to lines` - use batch mode to convert all 5 polygons at once.
2. Merge the line layers created in step 1 to one line layer using `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Merge vector layers`
3. Create a new polygon layer that covers the maximum extent of all your original polygons. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Extract layer extent` on the lines layer created in step 2.
4. Now split the polygon created in step 3 with the lines from step 2 using `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Split with lines`
5. You will get a new layer where each the original polygons are split up to several polygons, one for each category: no overlap with other polygons, overlapping with one, with two polygons etc. Create a new attribute with field calculator that counts the number of orginal polygons that overlap using the following expression (explanation below).

*Remark: In line 3, in paranthesis insert the names of the layers that contain your original polygons. In my case, they are named `layer1`,`layer2` etc. - don't forget the single quotes `'` around the layer names.*

```
array_sum( 
    array_foreach (
    array ('layer1','layer2','layer3','layer4','layer5'),
        case
        when  
            within( 
                point_on_surface( $geometry),  
                aggregate( 
                    @element, 
                    'collect', 
                    $geometry
                )
            ) 
        then 1
        else 0
        end
    )
)
```

**Explanation**: the expression creates a point inside the splitted polygons (`point_on_surface( $geometry)`) from step 4 and then for each of your original layers loops through (using `array_foreach`) an expression that looks if (`case when`) this point is `within` (line 6) layer1, layer2 etc.: the `aggregate()` function on line 8 to 12 that takes the layer-name for each loop from `@element`: this refers to the arguments of the `array()` in line 3. Each time the point is within the polygon, the output value is set to 1, otherwiese to 0 (line 14-15). The output is an array like e.g. `[ 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 ]`. So now just get the sum of the elements contained in the array with `array_sum( )` and you get: `3` (in this example.

*Screenshot: the result for 5 polygons (outlined in different colors). The label indicates for each splitted part how many polygons overlap there:*
[image]