# How to create single polygons from overlapping polygons and sum attributes

Tags: qgis-3, overlapping-features

I would like to achieve the following:
[image]

All the polygons are located on a single layer.
I already tried to use SAGA self intersection with the "power" as an identifier, but I get wrong duplicates and overlapping polygons boundaries.

[image]

Comment: My problem with this method is that I get some faulty polygons (as shown on my post, the last image) and not the sum of all the overlapping polygons, only for the intersection of 2 polygons.

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392905/88814

Comment: I don't understand your second image.  Also, what do you mean by "faulty polygon"?

Comment: Looks like you hit at least three polygons with the i-tool, I dont think there's anything wrong. Try completing the workflow in the answer I linked to